# simplifying expressions with hyperbolic functions

Tags: sympy

Is there a command in sympy to simplify sinh(x)+cosh(x) to exp(x)? If I issue

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
(sinh(x)+cosh(x)).simplify()
```

I just get sinh(x)+cosh(x) back, but I want to see exp(x) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even assuming that the `simplify` function in sympy was very good, what you suggest may not have worked, because what is "simple" is not rigorously defined.

I think what you want is the functionality present in `.rewrite`:

```
In [1]: (sinh(x)+cosh(x)).rewrite(exp)
Out[1]: 
 x
e
```

You can use `.rewrite` for many other transformations including gamma <-> combinatorics and inverse trig <-> logarithms.

Comment: For log -> trig rewriting, use `rewrite(sin)` rather than `sinh`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157724/simplifying-exponential-representation-of-hyperbolic-functions-in-sympy