# Simplifying exponential representation of hyperbolic functions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to rewrite some exponential functions in an expression to cosh and sinh. The rewrite() function works to get from a hyperbolic function to its exponential representation. But it does not work to get back.

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x=sympy.Symbol('x')
>>> sympy.cosh(x).rewrite(sympy.exp)
exp(x)/2 + exp(-x)/2
>>> sympy.cosh(x).rewrite(sympy.exp).rewrite(sympy.cosh)
exp(x)/2 + exp(-x)/2
```

I would expect the result of the last command to be 'cosh(x)'. Can someone explain to me why it is not?
I tried to find some documentation on the rewrite() function but the only bit I found was the short section in http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html that is not really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Applying `.rewrite(sympy.cos)` returns `cosh(x)` as you wanted. Apparently, the hyperbolic cosine is treated by `rewrite`  as a variant of the normal one.

Here is a [reference on rewrite method](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.rewrite).

Alternatively, `simplify(expr)` also transforms  `exp(x)/2 + exp(-x)/2` into `cosh(x)`.